# How to clear the contents of a row in a table with a dropdown list of names which match one of the columns of the table

Tags: excel, dropdown

Excel 2007 VBA - Two sheets, one of which contains a table, in the 3rd column of the table is the Name field.  On another sheet there is a dropdown list populated with the names from that table.  I am attempting to code that when a name is selected via the dropdown list it finds the corresponding row in the table and clears the contents without changing the table structure.

This is my first post so thanks in advance - Joe.

EDIT...

OK, I got the following code to work (as opposed to the stuff I first posted), what I need to do now is alter the code so that it only clears the row of the table not the entire row of the worksheet, any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeII(ByVal Target As Range)
   
   
If Not Intersect(Target, shOP19.Range("Scratch_Horse")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strHorse As String
    strHorse = shOP19.Range("Scratch_Horse")
    For Each cell In shPLine.Range("a2:s21")
        If Trim(cell.Value) = Trim(strHorse) Then
            cell.EntireRow.ClearContents
            shOP19.Range("B17").Value = "Horse"
            shOP19.Range("P1").Value = "Speed"
        End If
    Next cell
    Race_Sort ("PLine_Speed")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

sub on the code section of the dropdown sheet

Comment: What's the table called?

Comment: It is called RaceDB but I was testing hard coding and used...  shPLine.Range("a2:s21")